# INIT: id [ID] respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes

Tags: linux, centos, redhat-enterprise-linux, init

INIT: id "s21" respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes

[image: Picture Here]

One of my plants has been receiving this message at the main server terminal for a couple months now. I've Googled but can't seem to find any valid fixes.

We have a modem connected to the server, this allows use to connect to the server through the modem in case the internet goes down at this location. I'm thinking this is related.

I've looked into `/etc/inittab` to find s21 and how it's used. Here is the line:

```
# ESP 2
s21:2345:respawn:/sbin/agetty -L 9600 ttyQ02e1 wyse60
```

I don't understand why it's respawning. If it's respawning, doesn't that mean something it killing it? Is it crashing?

Any tips and suggestions would be helpful. I am close to the server location, so I can make drive if I need to fix this in person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further investigation, it would seem the modem is not connected to ttyQ02e1

It's connected to USB by an adaptor. It's safe to comment out the troublesome line and reload inittab

Also, according to dmesg, the system is trying to assign USB2-1 to ttyUSB0.

No more testing can be done on my side. By the end of the day, someone in the department found in their notes that the service on the modem was canceled a few years ago. Explains why I spent so much time trying to communicate with the modem to ensure I leave things working after my fixes. -.-